# Why does Google App Engine MySQL JDBC URL doesn't connect with the Database?

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, servlets, gcloud

I am developing a Website in which there is a register.jsp page. The RegistrationServlet.java fetches the details from register.jsp and stores all details into my gcloud database table "users". 
The problem is after deploying, it doesn't store any data into the Database. If I run it locally, it stores the data in the local db. But I don't understand why the data is not getting stored on the cloud db.

Note: I am following the official documentation and this is not a Maven project.

The following is the RegistrationServlet.java code:-

```
    @WebServlet({"/RegistrationServlet"})
public class RegistrationServlet
  extends HttpServlet
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public RegistrationServlet() {}

  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
  {}

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String first_name = request.getParameter("f1");
    String last_name = request.getParameter("l1");
    String phone = request.getParameter("p1");
    String email = request.getParameter("e1");
    String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
    String user_dob = request.getParameter("udate");
    String password = request.getParameter("pwd");



    UserData ud = new UserData();

    ud.setFirst_name(first_name);
    ud.setLast_name(last_name);
    ud.setUname(uname);
    ud.setPhone(phone);
    ud.setEmail(email);
    ud.setUser_dob(user_dob);
    ud.setPassword(password);


    if ((first_name.isEmpty()) || (last_name.isEmpty()) || (phone.isEmpty()) || (email.isEmpty()) || (password.isEmpty())) {
      RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Register.jsp");
      out.println("<font color=red>Please fill all the fields</font>");
      rd.include(request, response);
    }
    else
    {
      try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      }
      catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      System.out.println("Connecting to the Database");

      try
      {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://google/my_database_name?cloudSqlInstance=my_instance_connection_name&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=root&password=my_password&useSSL=false");

System.out.println("Connected to the Database");
        String query = "insert into liveinbliss.users values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);



        ps.setString(1, first_name);


        ps.setString(2, last_name);


        ps.setString(3, uname);


        ps.setString(4, phone);


        ps.setString(5, email);


        ps.setString(6, user_dob);


        ps.setString(7, password);



        ps.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("successfuly inserted");



        ps.close();




        con.close();


      }
      catch (SQLException e)
      {

        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      HttpSession session = request.getSession();
      session.setAttribute("username", first_name);
      response.sendRedirect("Success.jsp");






    }
  }
}
```

and the following is the error log:-

```
    Oct 07, 2018 9:05:54 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value '/Users/shashankk/Library/Application Support/google-cloud-tools-java/managed-cloud-sdk/LATEST/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/config/sdk/logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from '/Users/shashankk/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/LIB/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml'
2018-10-07 21:05:54.926:INFO::main: Logging initialized @889ms
2018-10-07 21:05:55.430:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.18.v20170406
2018-10-07 21:05:58.040:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed time=2389ms
2018-10-07 21:05:58.439:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started c.g.a.t.d.j.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@1e04fa0a{/,file:///Users/shashankk/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/LIB/,AVAILABLE}{/Users/shashankk/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/LIB}
2018-10-07 21:05:58.451:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started NetworkTrafficSelectChannelConnector@21e360a{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{localhost:8080}
2018-10-07 21:05:58.465:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @4428ms
Oct 07, 2018 3:35:58 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService startHotDeployScanner
INFO: Full scan of the web app in place every 1s.
Oct 07, 2018 3:35:58 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8080/
Oct 07, 2018 3:35:58 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
Oct 07, 2018 9:05:58 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
Oct 07, 2018 9:06:01 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Oct 07, 2018 9:06:01 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /signin.css
Connecting to the Database
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create socket factory 'com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory' due to underlying exception: 
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.createSocketFactory(MysqlIO.java:3333)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:297)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2197)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2230)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2025)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:778)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at controller.RegistrationServlet.doPost(RegistrationServlet.java:84)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1772)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1751)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.doScope(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:239)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.createSocketFactory(MysqlIO.java:3331)
    ... 61 more
Oct 07, 2018 9:06:42 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Oct 07, 2018 9:06:42 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /signin.css
Oct 07, 2018 9:06:42 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /dashboard.css
```

Thank you

Comment: **this is not a Maven project** - so ***what tool*** do you use to manage your dependencies? because the exception means that you do NOT have `SocketFactory` class in your classpath.

Comment: if you manage your dependencies *manually* you should download this **.jar** and add it to your classpath *manually*: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.sql/mysql-socket-factory/1.0.11